# SP13: Archiving Pages

Tags: 2013, search, search-scope, records-management

I am working in SharePoint 2013 an I have been tasked to archiving some pages that are outdated, however, cannot be deleted (eDiscovery).  The organization did not purchased the Records Management features of SharePoint that 2013 offers.  So, I am not sure what the best practices/steps that should be taken.  The process I was going to take is as follows: change the permissions of the page to only the administrators.  Or create a document library (archiving) and add the pages to the library.  This should avoid the page to appear in the search results.  I am aware there's third party software, however,  that's additional costs.  There should be way to archive with only out of box features.  This may seem as a simple question but not having access to the full capabilities of 2013 version I want to make sure I am archiving correctly.

Can anyone help me with the best steps/practices to use to archiving without all the 2013 version features? Thanks for your assistance it's appreciated.

Comment: What version of 2013 are you using? Foundation, Standard, ???

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I am using SharePoint 2013 Server Enterprise.

Comment: OK, if you have Enterprise you have all the features, there is no "additional purchase". I am wondering what features you think are missing.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott  Thank you Matthew.  That may mean that my organization did not turn the Records Management feature on.

Comment: They are usually Site Collection scoped features, so if you are a site collection admin you should be able to light them up.

Answer (score 1):

A retention policy may do the trick:

Library Settings => Information Management Policy settings => Choose Content Type => Enable Retention => Add a Retention stage => Set up your rules

http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/